# How to apply a constraint so that a generator should run for atleast 4 intervals?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pyomo

I was writing an optimization problem statement using Pyomo. It is a general problem statement:

- There is a demand profile of **96 blocks**.
- There are 2 main generators of **700kW** **(gen 1 and gen 2)** and one backup generator of **1000kW**.
- Two separate price lists **price 1 and price 2** for generators and the backup generator is the costliest one.
- Generators are exclusive in nature which means only 1 generator ll be active at a time and the rest of the energy ll come from a backup generator.
- Last and the most important thing is if the generator is active then it should remain active for the **next 4 blocks**. This is where I am facing the issue.

I have created a concrete model for this in Pyomo. Here is the code for it.

```
import numpy as np
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(96)
prices = {
    'price 1': np.random.randint(1,20,96),
    'price 2': np.random.randint(1,20,96),
}
load_profile = np.random.randint(500,1000,96)

generator_capacities = {
    'gen 1': 700,
    'gen 2': 700,
    'backup gen': 1000,
}

backup_cost = 10000

model = ConcreteModel()

# Define decision variables
model.m_index = Set(initialize=list(range(len(load_profile))))
model.gen1_output = Var(model.m_index, domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.gen2_output = Var(model.m_index, domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.backup_gen_output = Var(model.m_index, domain=NonNegativeReals)

# Define binary variables for gen1 and gen2
model.gen1_active = Var(model.m_index, within=Binary, initialize=1)
model.gen2_active = Var(model.m_index, within=Binary, initialize=0)

model.gen1_continuous_duration = Var(model.m_index, within=Binary)
model.gen2_continuous_duration = Var(model.m_index, within=Binary)



model.load_data = Param(model.m_index, initialize=dict(zip(model.m_index, load_profile)))


def cost(model):
    gen1_cost = sum(model.gen1_output[m] * prices['price 1'][m] for m in model.m_index)
    gen2_cost = sum(model.gen2_output[m] * prices['price 2'][m] for m in model.m_index)
    lost_load = sum(model.backup_gen_output[m] for m in model.m_index)

    total_cost = gen1_cost + gen2_cost + lost_load * backup_cost
    return total_cost


model.obj = Objective(rule=cost, sense=minimize)



def load_constraint_rule(model, m):
    return (
        model.gen1_output[m] + model.gen2_output[m] + model.backup_gen_output[m] == load_profile[m]
    )

model.load_constraint = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=load_constraint_rule)

def gen1_max(model, m):
    eq = model.gen1_output[m] <= 700 * model.gen1_active[m]
    return eq

model.gen1_max = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=gen1_max)

def gen2_max(model, m):
    eq = model.gen2_output[m] <= 700 * model.gen2_active[m]
    return eq

model.gen2_max = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=gen2_max)

def backup_max(model, m):
    eq = model.backup_gen_output[m] <= 1000
    return eq

model.backup_max = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=backup_max)

def exclusive_gen_operation_rule(model, m):
    return model.gen1_active[m] + model.gen2_active[m] <= 1

model.exclusive_gen_operation = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=exclusive_gen_operation_rule)

def gen1_continuous(model, m):
    interval = 4
    if m == 0:
        return Constraint.Skip
    elif m == 1:
        if (model.gen1_active[m-1] == 1):
            if m <= 96 - interval:
                eq = sum([model.gen1_active[i] for i in range(m, m + interval)]) == interval
                return eq
            else:
                return Constraint.Skip
        else:
            return Constraint.Skip
    elif m >= 2:
        if (model.gen1_active[m-1] == 1 and model.gen1_active[m-2] == 0):
            if m <= 96 - interval:
                eq = sum([model.gen1_active[i] for i in range(m, m + interval)]) == interval
                return eq
            else:
                return Constraint.Skip
        else:
            return Constraint.Skip

model.gen1_continuous = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=gen1_continuous)

def gen2_continuous(model, m):
    interval = 4
    if m == 0:
        return Constraint.Skip
    elif m == 1:
        if (model.gen2_active[m-1] == 1):
            if m <= 96 - interval:
                eq = sum([model.gen2_active[i] for i in range(m, m + interval)]) == interval
                return eq
            else:
                return Constraint.Skip
        else:
            return Constraint.Skip
    elif m >= 2:
        if (model.gen2_active[m-1] == 1 and model.gen2_active[m-2] == 0):
            if m <= 96 - interval:
                eq = sum([model.gen2_active[i] for i in range(m, m + interval)]) == interval
                return eq
            else:
                return Constraint.Skip
        else:
            return Constraint.Skip

model.gen2_continuous = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=gen2_continuous)




# def duration_constraint1_rule(model, m):
#     T = 4  # Desired minimum duration
#     if m <= 96 - T:
#         return sum(model.gen1_active[i] for i in range(m, m + T)) == T
#     return Constraint.Skip
#
# model.duration_constraint1 = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=duration_constraint1_rule)
#
# def duration_constraint2_rule(model, m):
#     T = 4  # Desired minimum duration
#     if m <= 96 - T:
#         return sum(model.gen2_active[i] for i in range(m, m + T)) == T
#     return Constraint.Skip
#
# model.duration_constraint2 = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=duration_constraint2_rule)
#
#
# def continuous_sync_rule(model, m):
#     return model.gen1_active[m] == model.gen1_continuous_duration[m]
#
# model.continuous_sync1 = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=continuous_sync_rule)
#
# def continuous_sync_rule(model, m):
#     return model.gen2_active[m] == model.gen2_continuous_duration[m]
#
# model.continuous_sync2 = Constraint(model.m_index, rule=continuous_sync_rule)


opt = SolverFactory('gurobi')  # Use a solver of your choice
results = opt.solve(model)

if results.solver.termination_condition == TerminationCondition.optimal:
    print("Optimal solution found")
else:
    print("Solver did not find an optimal solution")

output={}
for gen in ['gen1', 'gen2', 'backup_gen']:
    values = [model.__getattribute__(gen + '_output')[hour].value for hour in model.m_index]
    output[gen] = values
    # print(f"{gen} output: {values}")

for gen in ['gen1', 'gen2']:
    values = [model.__getattribute__(gen + '_active')[hour].value for hour in model.m_index]
    output[gen + ' switch'] = values
    # print(f"{gen} active:", values)

output['price 1'] = prices['price 1']
output['price 2'] = prices['price 2']
output['Load profile'] = load_profile
pd.DataFrame(output).to_excel('gen switches.xlsx')

# print(prices)
```

**gen1_continuous** and **gen2_continuous** are the constraints where I am trying the apply this condition where if gen1 is active then it should remain active for **next 4 blocks** but it is not working properly. Can anyone please help?
The expected output should be like this. This is the output from the model( Since this I am using random data you might get different output):
[image]

However, expected output in **gen1 switch** and **gen2 switch** should be like this based on the prices that you are seeing in the above image.
[image]

Comment: For exactly four time blocks, or for at least four time blocks?

Comment: For atleast 4 time blocks. You can see in the expected output that sometimes 1 is occurring more than 4 times that is because after 4 values  set to 1 it ll check for the prices in the next block and if the same switch has the minimum price then it ll pick that only and again set the 4 values as 1

Comment: Please only generate your random data after setting a fixed seed, for reproducibility.

Comment: I am sorry for that but i hope u do understand the problem statement?

Comment: I have fixed the values for prices and load profiles and updated the code@Reinderien

Comment: Have you? I still don't see a seed.

Comment: By seed do you mean fixed values for the input data ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254891/discussion-between-reinderien-and-vesper).

Comment: A general strategy for doing this is to use 2 variables for each of the generators: 1 for when it starts, 2nd for if it is "running." Here are a couple examples:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65425532/how-to-include-a-variable-in-the-summation-bound-of-a-objective-function-with-py/65427469#65427469
  and Constraint #3 here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76858056/shift-scheduling-optimization-using-linear-programming-in-pulp/76871673#76871673

(edited:  fixed duplicate link)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a strategy that I think works and answers your constraints.  As mentioned in the comment, I think it is efficient to use 2 variables with linkage to model the relationship between "starting" and "running"

```
Start => forces next 4 (or till end) periods to be running
Running <= only if started or running in previous period
```

Double indexing this is prudent as well, especially if you are going to add more sources.  I moved around a little furniture with your data, and lowered the min load by a bit because the backup always seems to run in original data because the odds of load going higher that 700 with a minimum of 500 in any 4 periods is quite high.

I put in a little "sugar" in the objective to cease unnecessary running.  If you remove that, the backup will start in the first period and happily idle along the whole time, picking up load where necessary.  Probably not desired.

##### Code:

```
# Generation Scheduling

import numpy as np
from pyomo.core import sum_product
from pyomo.environ import Var, Set, NonNegativeReals, Binary, Param, Objective, minimize, ConcreteModel, Constraint, \
    SolverFactory, TerminationCondition
# from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory
import pandas as pd

# np.random.seed(96)
time_periods = 100
backup_cost = 10000

prices = {
    (gen, time): np.random.randint(1, 20) for gen in ['Bertha', 'Sammy'] for time in range(time_periods)
}
for t in range(time_periods):
    prices['Backup', t] = backup_cost

load_profile = np.random.randint(200, 1000, time_periods)

generator_capacities = {
    'Bertha': 700,
    'Sammy': 700,
    'Backup': 1000,
}

model = ConcreteModel()

### SETS
model.T = Set(initialize=list(range(len(load_profile))), doc='time')
model.G = Set(initialize=generator_capacities.keys(), doc='generator')

### VARS
model.output = Var(model.G, model.T, domain=NonNegativeReals)
# Define binary variables for gen1 and gen2
model.gen_active = Var(model.G, model.T, domain=Binary)
model.gen_start = Var(model.G, model.T, domain=Binary)

### PARAMS
model.demand = Param(model.T, initialize=dict(zip(model.T, load_profile)))
model.capacity = Param(model.G, initialize=generator_capacities)
model.price = Param(model.G, model.T, initialize=prices)

### OBJ

# cost to idle generator.  If you don't do this, the backup will always be "active" even if no output
active_penalty = 0.1
model.obj = Objective(expr=sum_product(model.price, model.output) + 
                           active_penalty * sum(model.gen_active[g, t] for g in model.G for t in model.T))



### Constraints

@model.Constraint(model.T)
def meet_demand(model, t):
    return sum(model.output[g, t] for g in model.G) >= model.demand[t]

@model.Constraint(model.G, model.T)
def dont_overspeed_generator(model, g, t):
    return model.output[g, t] <= model.capacity[g] * model.gen_active[g, t]

@model.Constraint(model.T)
def select_generator(model, t):
    return sum(model.gen_active[g, t] for g in model.G - {'Backup',}) <= 1

@model.Constraint(model.G, model.T)
def min_runtime(model, g, t):
    """any generator that is started must run for 4 periods, unless in final 3 periods"""
    run_times = set(range(t, min(t+4, model.T.last())))
    return sum(model.gen_active[g, tt] for tt in run_times) >= len(run_times) * model.gen_start[g, t]

@model.Constraint(model.G, model.T)
def continuity(model, g, t):
    """can only be running if started in this period or running in previous"""
    if t == model.T.first():
        return model.gen_active[g, t] <= model.gen_start[g, t]
    else:
        return model.gen_active[g, t] <= model.gen_start[g, t] + model.gen_active[g, t-1]

# model.pprint()

opt = SolverFactory('cbc')  # Use a solver of your choice
results = opt.solve(model)

if results.solver.termination_condition == TerminationCondition.optimal:
    print("Optimal solution found")
else:
    print("Solver did not find an optimal solution")

output = {}
output['Load profile'] = load_profile
for gen in model.G:
    values = [model.output[gen, hour].value for hour in model.T]
    output[f'{gen} output'] = values
    # print(f"{gen} output: {values}")

for gen in model.G:
    values = [model.gen_active[gen, hour].value for hour in model.T]
    output[f'{gen} active'] = values
    # print(f"{gen} active:", values)
for gen in model.G :
    values = [model.gen_start[gen, hour].value for hour in model.T]
    output[f'{gen} start'] = values

for gen in model.G - {'Backup'}:
    price_list = []
    for t in range(time_periods):
        price_list.append(prices[gen, t])
    output[f'{gen} price'] = price_list
df = pd.DataFrame(output)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', 300)

print(df)
```

##### Output (very wide)

```
    Load profile  Bertha output  Sammy output  Backup output  Bertha active  Sammy active  Backup active  Bertha start  Sammy start  Backup start  Bertha price  Sammy price
0            405          405.0           0.0            0.0            1.0           0.0            0.0           1.0          0.0           0.0             2           11
1            780          700.0           0.0           80.0            1.0           0.0            1.0           0.0          0.0           1.0            19           17
2            620          620.0           0.0            0.0            1.0           0.0            1.0           0.0          0.0           0.0             6           12
3            273          273.0           0.0            0.0            1.0           0.0            1.0           0.0          0.0           0.0            17            7
4            958          700.0           0.0          258.0            1.0           0.0            1.0           0.0          0.0           0.0             8           17
5            777          700.0           0.0           77.0            1.0           0.0            1.0           0.0          0.0           0.0             9           16
6            510            0.0         510.0            0.0            0.0           1.0            0.0           0.0          1.0           0.0            14            1
```

Comment: ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for constraint min_runtime with
    index ('Bertha', 0): AttributeError: 'SimpleSet' object has no attribute
    'last'
ERROR: Constructing component 'min_runtime' from data=None failed:
    AttributeError: 'SimpleSet' object has no attribute 'last'

Comment: this code is giving me this error.

Comment: Something is wrong in your environment....  The type of that set should *not* be `SimpleSet`.  What version of `pyomo` are you using?  Did you run the code as-is in isolation or in some notebook with other imports?

Comment: Using the imports as stated w/ `pyomo` version 6.6, the type of both sets should be `OrderedScalarSet`.

Comment: my pyomo version is 5.6.

Comment: Ditch that, it's years outdated.  `pip install --upgrade pyomo`.  Or if you are an Anaconda user, update through that, etc.

Comment: okay, and just one more thing. I still need to run you program but I can still see some error in the output that you have shared. As you can see in the Bertha Output there are 6 continuous values. There should be 4 or 8 or 12 etc for example if Bertha is at lower price in should pick Berth for 0,1,2,3 positions. After that its should check the prices at 4th iteration, if again Bertha is at lower price then for 4,5,6,7 positions it should pick Bertha.

Comment: I interpreted your problem to be that the generator must run for *at least* 4 blocks to make it worth starting up.... then it could continue on for as long as pricing makes sense.  (the whole model assumes perfect foresight of price).  If you are only checking the price in every 4th slot or making decisions for exactly 4 slots at a time, then you are making non-existent/unnecessary times slots and you should just make 4-block decisions instead of subdividing

Comment: Yes in real world this would make more sense because each generator has their own ramp up rates and after that they can work on their own. But here it is just an example where data doesn’t make any sense. I just need to understand this concept where we can enforce something for certain amount of time in a time series data.

Comment: Well, the `min_runtime` constraint does exactly that.  And the `continuity` constraint is the piece you will be missing when you get to the next phase.  ;)

Comment: So can u update that acc to my expected output ?

Comment: I understand the code in the min_runtime constraint and it works perfectly. But yes i guess the continuity constraint needs to be changed for the desired output. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: It isn't clear what you want to do here.  You appear to be modeling a system with hourly decisions, but chopping it (for some reason I don't understand) into 15 minute time increments.  I would just switch to hours and be done.  I think this answers your original question.  Do some more work, if you get stuck, post a new Q.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have Pyomo so I demonstrate in PuLP.

This approach has a lot of surrounding bits that would be needed in a professional setting (and aren't strictly necessary to demonstrate the "at-least-4" question):

- Good indices
- Clear units
- Careful treatment of the market variation spectrum, and an example of a market where generator prices and demand are correlated
- Problem construction that digests price segments so that unambiguous variables are fixed, to minimize LP burden

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pulp
from numpy.random import default_rng


def make_sample_spectra(
    n_blocks: int = 96,
    price_max: float = 20,
    load_min: float = 2_000,
    load_max: float = 4_000,
    bandwidth: float = 6,     # Higher means noisier prices and loads
) -> tuple[
    np.ndarray,  # generator 1 price series
    np.ndarray,  # generator 2 price series
    np.ndarray,  # load profile
]:
    def rand_spectrum() -> np.ndarray:
        return band_weight * (
            rand.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=n_blocks//2) +
            rand.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=n_blocks//2)*1j
        )

    rand = default_rng(seed=0)

    # Exp-decay spectral weight controlled by bandwidth parameter
    band_weight = 0.01 + 0.99*np.exp(-np.arange(n_blocks//2)/bandwidth)

    # Some central price series on which all of the generator prices are based
    central_spectrum = np.empty(n_blocks//2 + 1, dtype=complex)
    central_spectrum[0] = price_max/2
    central_spectrum[1:] = price_max/8 * rand_spectrum()

    # Generator-specific prices and load (demand) are correlated to central prices
    gen1_spectrum = central_spectrum.copy()
    gen1_spectrum[1:] += 1.0 * rand_spectrum()
    gen2_spectrum = central_spectrum.copy()
    gen2_spectrum[1:] += 1.0 * rand_spectrum()
    load_spectrum = central_spectrum*(load_max - load_min)/30
    load_spectrum[0] = (load_max + load_min)/2
    load_spectrum[1:] += (load_max - load_min)/10 * rand_spectrum()

    # Convert from spectra to real time series
    gen1_price = np.fft.irfft(gen1_spectrum, norm='forward')
    gen2_price = np.fft.irfft(gen2_spectrum, norm='forward')
    load_profile = np.fft.irfft(load_spectrum, norm='forward')

    return gen1_price.clip(min=0), gen2_price.clip(min=0), load_profile.clip(min=0)


def plot_inputs(
    gen1_price: np.ndarray,
    gen2_price: np.ndarray,
    load_profile: np.ndarray,
) -> plt.Figure:
    fig: plt.Figure
    ax: plt.Axes
    ax_load: plt.Axes
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax_load = ax.twinx()  # Put load on a secondary y-axis

    hour = np.arange(start=0, stop=len(gen1_price)*15/60, step=0.25)

    ax.plot(hour, gen1_price, label='gen1 price')
    ax.plot(hour, gen2_price, label='gen2 price')
    ax_load.plot(hour, load_profile, c='black', label='load profile')

    ax.set_title('Correlated, bandwidth-limited sample market series')
    ax.set_xlabel('Time of day (h)')
    ax.set_ylabel('Price ($/kWh)')
    ax_load.set_ylabel('Load profile (kWh)')
    ax.legend(loc='lower left')
    ax_load.legend(loc='lower right')

    return fig


def make_vars(
    gen1_price: np.ndarray,
    gen2_price: np.ndarray,
    load_profile: np.ndarray,
) -> tuple[
    pd.DataFrame,  # data per block
    pd.DataFrame,  # data per generator and block
]:
    blocks_per_hour = 4
    n_hours = len(gen1_price) // blocks_per_hour
    minutes_per_block = 60//blocks_per_hour

    # Simple index of 15-minute intervals
    block_idx = pd.TimedeltaIndex(
        name='block',
        data=np.arange(0, n_hours*60, minutes_per_block),
        unit='m',
    )

    # Multi-index over all blocks and generators
    mindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((
        pd.Index(name='generator', data=('gen1', 'gen2', 'backup')),
        block_idx,
    ))

    generators = pd.DataFrame(index=mindex)
    generators.loc['gen1', 'pkwh'] = gen1_price  # dollars per kilowatt hour
    generators.loc['gen2', 'pkwh'] = gen2_price
    generators.loc['backup', 'pkwh'] = 50
    generators['pkwb'] = generators['pkwh'] / blocks_per_hour  # dollars per kilowatt block
    generators.loc['gen1', 'capacity'] = 700
    generators.loc['gen2', 'capacity'] = 700
    generators.loc['backup', 'capacity'] = 1_000

    # data applicable to each block (not per generator)
    blocks = pd.DataFrame(
        {'load_kwh': load_profile},
        index=block_idx,
    )
    blocks['load_kwb'] = load_profile / blocks_per_hour  # kilowatt blocks

    # signed affordability difference between prices, per block
    blocks['aff_delta'] = generators.loc['gen1', 'pkwb'] - generators.loc['gen2', 'pkwb']
    blocks['aff_change'] = np.sign(  # places where affordability changes sign
        blocks['aff_delta']
    ).diff().fillna(0)
    blocks['aff_change_dist'] = np.abs(  # distance from closest affordability change
        np.arange(len(gen1_price))[:, np.newaxis] -
        blocks['aff_change'].values.nonzero()[0][np.newaxis, :]
    ).min(axis=1)

    # places where the generator selection can be performed unambiguously (without LP)
    blocks['unambiguous'] = blocks['aff_change_dist'] >= blocks_per_hour

    # fixed selection values where the affordability is unambiguous
    generators.loc['gen1', 'select'] = (
        blocks['unambiguous'] & (
            generators.loc['gen1', 'pkwb'] < generators.loc['gen2', 'pkwb']
        )
    ).align(generators)[0]
    generators.loc['gen2', 'select'] = (
        blocks['unambiguous'] & (
            generators.loc['gen1', 'pkwb'] > generators.loc['gen2', 'pkwb']
        )
    ).align(generators)[0]
    generators.loc['backup', 'select'] = (  # all backup is unambiguous
        blocks['load_kwb'] >
        generators.loc[['gen1', 'gen2'], 'capacity'].groupby(level='block').max()
    ).align(generators)[0]

    times = mindex.get_level_values('block').to_series(index=mindex)
    minute_names = (
        times.dt.components['hours']*100 + times.dt.components['minutes']
    ).apply('{:04.0f}'.format)

    # make a series of generator-block pair names, and create LpVariables out of it
    generators.loc[(['gen1', 'gen2'], block_idx[~blocks['unambiguous']]), 'select'] = (
        (
            'sel_' + mindex.get_level_values('generator') + '_' + minute_names
        ).loc[(['gen1', 'gen2'], block_idx[~blocks['unambiguous']])]
        .apply(pulp.LpVariable, cat=pulp.LpBinary)
    ).align(generators)[0]

    # power supplied (whether fixed or LP-variable)
    generators.loc[['gen1', 'gen2'], 'supplied'] = (
        blocks['load_kwb'].align(generators.loc[['gen1', 'gen2']])[0]
        .clip(upper=generators.loc[['gen1', 'gen2'], 'capacity'])
    )
    backup_power = (
        (
            blocks['load_kwb'] -
            generators.loc[['gen1', 'gen2'], 'capacity'].groupby(level='block').max()
        )
        .clip(lower=0)
    )
    for time, power_val in backup_power.items():
        generators.loc[('backup', time), 'supplied'] = power_val

    # price per block and generator (whether fixed or LP-variable)
    generators['price'] = generators['pkwb'] * generators['select'] * generators['supplied']

    def set_starts(select: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
        diffs = select.diff()
        # Variable whenever there is an affine expression
        might_be_start = diffs.apply(lambda d: isinstance(d, pulp.LpAffineExpression))
        might_be_start[0] |= select[0] == True
        might_be_start[-3:] = False

        for i in range(len(might_be_start) - 4):
            if any(s is False for s in select.iloc[i: i+4]):
                might_be_start[i] = False
        return might_be_start

    maybe_starts = (
        generators.loc[['gen1', 'gen2']]
        .select.groupby('generator', group_keys=False)
        .apply(set_starts)
    )
    start_vars = (
        (
            'start_' + mindex.get_level_values('generator') + '_' + minute_names
        ).loc[['gen1', 'gen2']][maybe_starts]
        .apply(pulp.LpVariable, cat=pulp.LpBinary)
    )
    generators.loc[start_vars.index, 'start'] = start_vars
    generators.start.fillna(False, inplace=True)

    # Ignore backup start - doesn't matter to the solution

    return blocks, generators


def dump_vars(blocks: pd.DataFrame, generators: pd.DataFrame) -> None:
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
    pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
    print(f'{blocks.unambiguous.sum()}/{len(blocks)} blocks are unambiguous'
          '\n'
          '\nWhat block data looks like prior to solve:')
    print(blocks.head(12))
    print('...'
          '\n'
          '\nWhat generator data looks like prior to solve:')
    print(generators.unstack(level='generator').head(12))
    print('...\n')


def fmt_timedelta(t: pd.Timedelta) -> str:
    return f'{t.components.hours:2d}{t.components.minutes:2d}'


def add_constraints(prob: pulp.LpProblem, generators: pd.DataFrame) -> None:
    # Exactly one generator must be selected per block
    for block, total in generators.loc[['gen1', 'gen2'], 'select'].groupby('block').sum().items():
        if isinstance(total, pulp.LpAffineExpression):
            prob.addConstraint(name=f'excl_{fmt_timedelta(block)}', constraint=total == 1)

    for generator, group in generators.loc[['gen1', 'gen2'], ['select', 'start']].groupby('generator'):
        for i in range(len(group)-1):
            start = group.start[i+1]
            if isinstance(start, pulp.LpVariable):
                # A start cannot be enabled if there is a selected before it or non-selected on it
                # A start must be enabled if there is a non-selected before it and selected on it
                prob.addConstraint(
                    name=f'starthi_{generator}_{i}',
                    constraint=start <= (group.select[i+1] - group.select[i] + 1)/2,
                )
                prob.addConstraint(
                    name=f'startlo_{generator}_{i}',
                    constraint=start >= group.select[i+1] - group.select[i],
                )

        # The four elements as of an enabled start must be selected
        for i in range(len(group)):
            start = group.start[i]
            if isinstance(start, pulp.LpVariable):
                for j in range(i, i+4):
                    prob.addConstraint(
                        name=f'starton_{generator}_{i}_{j}',
                        constraint=group.select[j] >= start,
                    )


def dump_solution(blocks: pd.DataFrame, generators: pd.DataFrame) -> None:
    generators[['select', 'start']] = (
        generators[['select', 'start']]
        .applymap(pulp.LpAffineExpression)
        .applymap(pulp.LpAffineExpression.value) > 0.5
    )
    generators['price'] = (
        generators['price']
        .apply(pulp.LpAffineExpression)
        .apply(pulp.LpAffineExpression.value)
    )

    summary = generators[['pkwb', 'capacity', 'supplied', 'price', 'select', 'start']].unstack(level='generator')
    summary['load'] = blocks['load_kwb']
    print(summary)


def main() -> None:
    gen1_price, gen2_price, load_profile = make_sample_spectra()
    plot_inputs(gen1_price, gen2_price, load_profile)
    # plt.show()

    blocks, generators = make_vars(gen1_price, gen2_price, load_profile)
    dump_vars(blocks, generators)

    prob = pulp.LpProblem(name='power_generation', sense=pulp.LpMinimize)
    prob.objective = generators['price'].sum()

    add_constraints(prob, generators)

    print(prob)
    prob.solve()
    assert prob.status == pulp.LpStatusOptimal

    dump_solution(blocks, generators)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
Result - Optimal solution found

Objective value:                76437.20611280
Enumerated nodes:               0
Total iterations:               0
Time (CPU seconds):             0.05
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.05

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.06   (Wallclock seconds):       0.06

                  pkwb                     capacity                  supplied                                price                           select                start                       load
generator       backup      gen1      gen2   backup   gen1   gen2      backup        gen1        gen2       backup         gen1         gen2 backup   gen1   gen2 backup   gen1   gen2             
block                                                                                                                                                                                              
0 days 00:00:00   12.5  2.777546  2.201681   1000.0  700.0  700.0    0.000000  630.875461  630.875461     0.000000     0.000000  1388.986739  False  False   True  False  False  False   630.875461
0 days 00:15:00   12.5  3.076080  2.224555   1000.0  700.0  700.0    0.000000  649.382154  649.382154     0.000000     0.000000  1444.585995  False  False   True  False  False  False   649.382154
0 days 00:30:00   12.5  3.406207  2.338785   1000.0  700.0  700.0    0.000000  639.095783  639.095783     0.000000     0.000000  1494.707562  False  False   True  False  False  False   639.095783
0 days 00:45:00   12.5  2.758682  1.678441   1000.0  700.0  700.0    0.000000  615.130875  615.130875     0.000000     0.000000  1032.461131  False  False   True  False  False  False   615.130875
0 days 01:00:00   12.5  1.623215  0.758829   1000.0  700.0  700.0    0.000000  583.680587  583.680587     0.000000     0.000000   442.913730  False  False   True  False  False  False   583.680587
0 days 01:15:00   12.5  0.679270  0.000000   1000.0  700.0  700.0    0.000000  577.814810  577.814810     0.000000     0.000000     0.000000  False  False   True  False  False  False   577.814810
0 days 01:30:00   12.5  0.443093  0.000000   1000.0  700.0  700.0    0.000000  611.123714  611.123714     0.000000     0.000000     0.000000  False  False   True  False  False  False   611.123714
0 days 01:45:00   12.5  0.681384  0.344272   1000.0  700.0  700.0    0.000000  673.923525  673.923525     0.000000     0.000000   232.012675  False  False   True  False  False  False   673.923525
0 days 02:00:00   12.5  0.961876  0.754140   1000.0  700.0  700.0   27.815850  700.000000  700.000000   347.698120     0.000000   527.898191   True  False   True  False  False  False   727.815850
0 days 02:15:00   12.5  1.289390  1.215769   1000.0  700.0  700.0   92.194725  700.000000  700.000000  1152.434067     0.000000   851.038403   True  False   True  False  False  False   792.194725
0 days 02:30:00   12.5  1.994865  2.156218   1000.0  700.0  700.0  153.105927  700.000000  700.000000  1913.824094  1396.405477     0.000000   True   True  False  False   True  False   853.105927
0 days 02:45:00   12.5  2.421644  2.858095   1000.0  700.0  700.0  173.758530  700.000000  700.000000  2171.981624  1695.151049     0.000000   True   True  False  False  False  False   873.758530
0 days 03:00:00   12.5  2.771886  3.352545   1000.0  700.0  700.0  142.316581  700.000000  700.000000  1778.957261  1940.320484     0.000000   True   True  False  False  False  False   842.316581
0 days 03:15:00   12.5  3.277075  3.732515   1000.0  700.0  700.0  115.165344  700.000000  700.000000  1439.566805  2293.952253     0.000000   True   True  False  False  False  False   815.165344
0 days 03:30:00   12.5  3.878684  4.324681   1000.0  700.0  700.0  140.984405  700.000000  700.000000  1762.305060  2715.078555     0.000000   True   True  False  False  False  False   840.984405
0 days 03:45:00   12.5  4.373724  4.855328   1000.0  700.0  700.0  168.917303  700.000000  700.000000  2111.466288  3061.606524     0.000000   True   True  False  False  False  False   868.917303
0 days 04:00:00   12.5  4.605355  5.187492   1000.0  700.0  700.0  198.367830  700.000000  700.000000  2479.597875  3223.748251     0.000000   True   True  False  False  False  False   898.367830
0 days 04:15:00   12.5  4.773074  5.486201   1000.0  700.0  700.0  230.212909  700.000000  700.000000  2877.661363  3341.151734     0.000000   True   True  False  False  False  False   930.212909
0 days 04:30:00   12.5  4.652874  5.329706   1000.0  700.0  700.0  224.535087  700.000000  700.000000  2806.688583  3257.011772     0.000000   True   True  False  False  False  False   924.535087
0 days 04:45:00   12.5  4.101426  4.876927   1000.0  700.0  700.0  190.677031  700.000000  700.000000  2383.462885  2870.998254     0.000000   True   True  False  False  False  False   890.677031
0 days 05:00:00   12.5  3.392417  4.406849   1000.0  700.0  700.0  157.659237  700.000000  700.000000  1970.740459  2374.691556     0.000000   True   True  False  False  False  False   857.659237
0 days 05:15:00   12.5  2.791241  3.801053   1000.0  700.0  700.0  109.076294  700.000000  700.000000  1363.453671  1953.868894     0.000000   True   True  False  False  False  False   809.076294
0 days 05:30:00   12.5  2.324818  3.252233   1000.0  700.0  700.0   76.054257  700.000000  700.000000   950.678209  1627.372303     0.000000   True   True  False  False  False  False   776.054257
0 days 05:45:00   12.5  2.008981  2.901358   1000.0  700.0  700.0   27.008893  700.000000  700.000000   337.611162  1406.286434     0.000000   True   True  False  False  False  False   727.008893
0 days 06:00:00   12.5  2.151037  3.117439   1000.0  700.0  700.0   26.299100  700.000000  700.000000   328.738750  1505.725808     0.000000   True   True  False  False  False  False   726.299100
0 days 06:15:00   12.5  2.528968  3.615626   1000.0  700.0  700.0   22.941703  700.000000  700.000000   286.771288  1770.277882     0.000000   True   True  False  False  False  False   722.941703
0 days 06:30:00   12.5  3.137843  4.524448   1000.0  700.0  700.0   62.176293  700.000000  700.000000   777.203658  2196.490149     0.000000   True   True  False  False  False  False   762.176293
0 days 06:45:00   12.5  3.890071  5.388080   1000.0  700.0  700.0   89.252203  700.000000  700.000000  1115.652534  2723.049577     0.000000   True   True  False  False  False  False   789.252203
0 days 07:00:00   12.5  4.353576  5.727415   1000.0  700.0  700.0  117.448358  700.000000  700.000000  1468.104478  3047.502950     0.000000   True   True  False  False  False  False   817.448358
0 days 07:15:00   12.5  3.898458  5.130238   1000.0  700.0  700.0   99.351763  700.000000  700.000000  1241.897038  2728.920519     0.000000   True   True  False  False  False  False   799.351763
0 days 07:30:00   12.5  3.539932  4.622750   1000.0  700.0  700.0   87.467451  700.000000  700.000000  1093.343143  2477.952630     0.000000   True   True  False  False  False  False   787.467451
0 days 07:45:00   12.5  3.658072  4.838244   1000.0  700.0  700.0   80.494090  700.000000  700.000000  1006.176125  2560.650233     0.000000   True   True  False  False  False  False   780.494090
0 days 08:00:00   12.5  3.942095  5.224735   1000.0  700.0  700.0   64.949679  700.000000  700.000000   811.870987  2759.466336     0.000000   True   True  False  False  False  False   764.949679
0 days 08:15:00   12.5  4.523772  5.668946   1000.0  700.0  700.0   65.355845  700.000000  700.000000   816.948057  3166.640666     0.000000   True   True  False  False  False  False   765.355845
0 days 08:30:00   12.5  5.083757  5.948543   1000.0  700.0  700.0   92.893641  700.000000  700.000000  1161.170508  3558.630174     0.000000   True   True  False  False  False  False   792.893641
0 days 08:45:00   12.5  5.643640  6.090270   1000.0  700.0  700.0  147.595375  700.000000  700.000000  1844.942189  3950.548124     0.000000   True   True  False  False  False  False   847.595375
0 days 09:00:00   12.5  5.972615  5.879718   1000.0  700.0  700.0  234.579995  700.000000  700.000000  2932.249940     0.000000  4115.802909   True  False   True  False  False   True   934.579995
0 days 09:15:00   12.5  5.823412  5.159475   1000.0  700.0  700.0  255.589624  700.000000  700.000000  3194.870296     0.000000  3611.632519   True  False   True  False  False  False   955.589624
0 days 09:30:00   12.5  5.051088  3.991017   1000.0  700.0  700.0  221.548361  700.000000  700.000000  2769.354517     0.000000  2793.711719   True  False   True  False  False  False   921.548361
0 days 09:45:00   12.5  4.074666  2.626331   1000.0  700.0  700.0  137.426951  700.000000  700.000000  1717.836887     0.000000  1838.431888   True  False   True  False  False  False   837.426951
0 days 10:00:00   12.5  3.164807  1.242414   1000.0  700.0  700.0   52.332313  700.000000  700.000000   654.153912     0.000000   869.689536   True  False   True  False  False  False   752.332313
0 days 10:15:00   12.5  2.410182  0.268348   1000.0  700.0  700.0    0.000000  669.350698  669.350698     0.000000     0.000000   179.618735  False  False   True  False  False  False   669.350698
0 days 10:30:00   12.5  2.256343  0.299352   1000.0  700.0  700.0    0.000000  644.920063  644.920063     0.000000     0.000000   193.057866  False  False   True  False  False  False   644.920063
0 days 10:45:00   12.5  2.357360  0.694478   1000.0  700.0  700.0    0.000000  621.717899  621.717899     0.000000     0.000000   431.769136  False  False   True  False  False  False   621.717899
0 days 11:00:00   12.5  2.487939  1.080508   1000.0  700.0  700.0    0.000000  592.574893  592.574893     0.000000     0.000000   640.281836  False  False   True  False  False  False   592.574893
0 days 11:15:00   12.5  2.811644  1.277883   1000.0  700.0  700.0    0.000000  610.865207  610.865207     0.000000     0.000000   780.614544  False  False   True  False  False  False   610.865207
0 days 11:30:00   12.5  2.789758  1.170209   1000.0  700.0  700.0    0.000000  629.087382  629.087382     0.000000     0.000000   736.163553  False  False   True  False  False  False   629.087382
0 days 11:45:00   12.5  2.426403  0.849900   1000.0  700.0  700.0    0.000000  625.575111  625.575111     0.000000     0.000000   531.676011  False  False   True  False  False  False   625.575111
0 days 12:00:00   12.5  1.910459  0.688194   1000.0  700.0  700.0    0.000000  600.884412  600.884412     0.000000     0.000000   413.524914  False  False   True  False  False  False   600.884412
0 days 12:15:00   12.5  2.052243  1.074815   1000.0  700.0  700.0    0.000000  602.356901  602.356901     0.000000     0.000000   647.422134  False  False   True  False  False  False   602.356901
0 days 12:30:00   12.5  2.702988  2.021001   1000.0  700.0  700.0    0.000000  611.339887  611.339887     0.000000     0.000000  1235.518396  False  False   True  False  False  False   611.339887
0 days 12:45:00   12.5  2.946376  2.666864   1000.0  700.0  700.0    0.000000  614.336737  614.336737     0.000000  1810.066758     0.000000  False   True  False  False   True  False   614.336737
0 days 13:00:00   12.5  2.698822  3.023901   1000.0  700.0  700.0    0.000000  620.312984  620.312984     0.000000  1674.114624     0.000000  False   True  False  False  False  False   620.312984
0 days 13:15:00   12.5  1.984529  2.428480   1000.0  700.0  700.0    0.000000  581.380557  581.380557     0.000000  1153.766378     0.000000  False   True  False  False  False  False   581.380557
0 days 13:30:00   12.5  1.760150  1.786823   1000.0  700.0  700.0    0.000000  571.964575  571.964575     0.000000  1006.743625     0.000000  False   True  False  False  False  False   571.964575
0 days 13:45:00   12.5  1.705284  1.239265   1000.0  700.0  700.0    0.000000  570.805558  570.805558     0.000000     0.000000   707.379271  False  False   True  False  False   True   570.805558
0 days 14:00:00   12.5  2.131344  1.439202   1000.0  700.0  700.0    0.000000  613.752250  613.752250     0.000000     0.000000   883.313264  False  False   True  False  False  False   613.752250
0 days 14:15:00   12.5  2.385605  1.770976   1000.0  700.0  700.0    0.000000  695.241170  695.241170     0.000000     0.000000  1231.255433  False  False   True  False  False  False   695.241170
0 days 14:30:00   12.5  2.133604  1.644812   1000.0  700.0  700.0   51.027184  700.000000  700.000000   637.839795     0.000000  1151.368399   True  False   True  False  False  False   751.027184
0 days 14:45:00   12.5  1.124016  0.806825   1000.0  700.0  700.0   57.854707  700.000000  700.000000   723.183841     0.000000   564.777816   True  False   True  False  False  False   757.854707
0 days 15:00:00   12.5  0.305059  0.000000   1000.0  700.0  700.0   80.741580  700.000000  700.000000  1009.269752     0.000000     0.000000   True  False   True  False  False  False   780.741580
0 days 15:15:00   12.5  0.026591  0.000000   1000.0  700.0  700.0   52.316958  700.000000  700.000000   653.961975     0.000000     0.000000   True  False   True  False  False  False   752.316958
0 days 15:30:00   12.5  0.089118  0.000000   1000.0  700.0  700.0   21.137181  700.000000  700.000000   264.214759     0.000000     0.000000   True  False   True  False  False  False   721.137181
0 days 15:45:00   12.5  0.000000  0.000000   1000.0  700.0  700.0    0.000000  688.229242  688.229242     0.000000     0.000000     0.000000  False  False   True  False  False  False   688.229242
0 days 16:00:00   12.5  0.000000  0.000000   1000.0  700.0  700.0    0.000000  648.905645  648.905645     0.000000     0.000000     0.000000  False  False   True  False  False  False   648.905645
0 days 16:15:00   12.5  0.000000  0.227087   1000.0  700.0  700.0    0.000000  649.107979  649.107979     0.000000     0.000000     0.000000  False   True  False  False   True  False   649.107979
0 days 16:30:00   12.5  0.000000  0.596062   1000.0  700.0  700.0    0.000000  685.215818  685.215818     0.000000     0.000000     0.000000  False   True  False  False  False  False   685.215818
0 days 16:45:00   12.5  0.000000  0.505486   1000.0  700.0  700.0   18.540039  700.000000  700.000000   231.750482     0.000000     0.000000   True   True  False  False  False  False   718.540039
0 days 17:00:00   12.5  0.000000  0.238658   1000.0  700.0  700.0   15.131182  700.000000  700.000000   189.139772     0.000000     0.000000   True   True  False  False  False  False   715.131182
0 days 17:15:00   12.5  0.000000  0.119532   1000.0  700.0  700.0    0.000000  681.037290  681.037290     0.000000     0.000000     0.000000  False   True  False  False  False  False   681.037290
0 days 17:30:00   12.5  0.223407  0.121176   1000.0  700.0  700.0    0.000000  625.070663  625.070663     0.000000     0.000000    75.743518  False  False   True  False  False   True   625.070663
0 days 17:45:00   12.5  1.078196  0.564489   1000.0  700.0  700.0    0.000000  652.272811  652.272811     0.000000     0.000000   368.201024  False  False   True  False  False  False   652.272811
0 days 18:00:00   12.5  1.211582  0.557742   1000.0  700.0  700.0    0.000000  698.580714  698.580714     0.000000     0.000000   389.627522  False  False   True  False  False  False   698.580714
0 days 18:15:00   12.5  1.516259  1.043904   1000.0  700.0  700.0   70.376871  700.000000  700.000000   879.710889     0.000000   730.732759   True  False   True  False  False  False   770.376871
0 days 18:30:00   12.5  1.884174  1.443605   1000.0  700.0  700.0   88.219662  700.000000  700.000000  1102.745772     0.000000  1010.523268   True  False   True  False  False  False   788.219662
0 days 18:45:00   12.5  2.376422  2.022819   1000.0  700.0  700.0  117.064718  700.000000  700.000000  1463.308979     0.000000  1415.973323   True  False   True  False  False  False   817.064718
0 days 19:00:00   12.5  2.541651  2.439658   1000.0  700.0  700.0  168.339581  700.000000  700.000000  2104.244760     0.000000  1707.760388   True  False   True  False  False  False   868.339581
0 days 19:15:00   12.5  2.369814  2.471768   1000.0  700.0  700.0  221.381879  700.000000  700.000000  2767.273488  1658.870053     0.000000   True   True  False  False   True  False   921.381879
0 days 19:30:00   12.5  2.414590  2.766189   1000.0  700.0  700.0  285.353157  700.000000  700.000000  3566.914466  1690.212673     0.000000   True   True  False  False  False  False   985.353157
0 days 19:45:00   12.5  2.791299  3.486532   1000.0  700.0  700.0  350.588333  700.000000  700.000000  4382.354159  1953.909126     0.000000   True   True  False  False  False  False  1050.588333
0 days 20:00:00   12.5  3.013210  3.904822   1000.0  700.0  700.0  399.657855  700.000000  700.000000  4995.723181  2109.247077     0.000000   True   True  False  False  False  False  1099.657855
0 days 20:15:00   12.5  3.040733  4.100468   1000.0  700.0  700.0  387.299328  700.000000  700.000000  4841.241599  2128.513322     0.000000   True   True  False  False  False  False  1087.299328
0 days 20:30:00   12.5  3.327073  4.428190   1000.0  700.0  700.0  328.752226  700.000000  700.000000  4109.402830  2328.951071     0.000000   True   True  False  False  False  False  1028.752226
...
```

[image: correlated market]