# Optimizing a batch process in pyomo Python - How to set a constant operational power for each batch?

Tags: python, optimization, batch-processing, linear-programming, pyomo

I want to optimize an industrial batch process using pyomo in Python. The objective function is to minimize the cost of the system. In my simplified example, I specify production costs with random values. The uniqueness of the batch process is:

1. That once the system is turned on, it must run for four or a multiple of four time steps (multiple batches in a row). --> That ist already implemented.
2. Once a batch is started, the operational power for this batch should be constant. --> Not solved

I tried already this constraint:

```
# Ensure that when the plant starts, it runs for the current and next three periods whith equal power.
def block_production_rule_1(model, t):
    if t <= T-3:
        return model.production[t+1]  >= model.production[t] * model.start[t]
    return pyo.Constraint.Skip
model.block_production_rule_1 = pyo.Constraint(model.timesteps, rule=block_production_rule_1)

def block_production_rule_2(model,t):
    if t <= T-3:
        return model.production[t+2] >= model.production[t] * model.start[t]
    return pyo.Constraint.Skip
model.block_production_rule_2 = pyo.Constraint(model.timesteps, rule=block_production_rule_2)

def block_production_rule_3(model,t):
    if t <= T-3:
        return model.production[t+3] >= model.production[t] * model.start[t]
    return pyo.Constraint.Skip
model.block_production_rule_3 = pyo.Constraint(model.timesteps, rule=block_production_rule_3)
```

But with this, I only ensure, that the operational power can´t become smaller in the course of the process.

Does anyone has an idea how I can solve this problem?

**Update**

I changed the objective to:

```
def obj_rule(model):
    return sum((production_cost[t-1] + production_cost[t] + production_cost[t+1] + production_cost[t+2]) * model.run_power[t] for t in model.timesteps)
model.obj = pyo.Objective(rule=obj_rule, sense=pyo.minimize)
```

If I don´t miss anything it is working now. I also changed some other parts in the code (see below).
**Code:**

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
import numpy as np
import random 


# Define the model
model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

# 1. Define the model, sets, and parameters.
T = 56  # number of timesteps
production_goal = 32
maxPower = 2
minPower = 0
model.timesteps = pyo.RangeSet(1, T)

# Production cost function
# production_cost = [1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 1, 0, 2, 4, 1, 3, 2, 0, 4, 2, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1,0,3,3,3]
production_cost = (np.sin(np.linspace(0, 8*np.pi, T)) + 1) * 50
production_cost = [_ for _ in range(T+3)]
production_cost = [random.randint(0,4) for _ in range(T+3)]
production_cost_sum = []
for i in range(len(production_cost)):
    total = 0
    for j in range(i, min(i + 4, len(production_cost))):  # Beachte das Randproblem am Ende
        total += production_cost[j]
    production_cost_sum.append(total)

# 2. Define the decision variables.
model.start = pyo.Var(model.timesteps, within=pyo.Binary)  # start of the plant
model.run_power = pyo.Var(model.timesteps, within=pyo.Integers)  # power of the plant

# 3. Define the objective function.
def obj_rule(model):
    return sum((production_cost[t-1] + production_cost[t] + production_cost[t+1] + production_cost[t+2]) * model.run_power[t] for t in model.timesteps)
model.obj = pyo.Objective(rule=obj_rule, sense=pyo.minimize)

# 4. Define the constraints.
# Total production constraint
def total_production_rule(model):
    return sum(model.run_power[t] for t in model.timesteps) == production_goal/4
model.total_production_con = pyo.Constraint(rule=total_production_rule)

# Production is only possible if plant is on
def production_on_rule_1(model, t):
    return model.run_power[t] <= model.start[t] * maxPower
model.production_on_con_1 = pyo.Constraint(model.timesteps, rule=production_on_rule_1)

def production_on_rule_2(model, t):
    return model.run_power[t] >= model.start[t] 
model.production_on_con_2 = pyo.Constraint(model.timesteps, rule=production_on_rule_2)


# Start if no start occurred in preceding 3 periods
def start_rule(model, t):
    return model.start[t] <= 1 - sum(model.start[tt] for tt in range(t-3, t) if tt > 0)
model.start_con = pyo.Constraint(model.timesteps, rule=start_rule)




# 5. Solve the model using Gurobi.
solver = pyo.SolverFactory('gurobi')
results = solver.solve(model)









import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# 6. Plot the results.
x_values = [model.run_power[t]() for t in model.timesteps]
i = 0
while i < len(x_values):
    if x_values[i] > 0:
        value_to_propagate = x_values[i]
        for j in range(i, min(i + 4, len(x_values))):
            x_values[j] = value_to_propagate
        i += 4
    else:
        i += 1
y_values = [model.run_power[t]() for t in model.timesteps]
batch_over_values = [model.start[t]() for t in model.timesteps]

# Create a plot with 3 subplots
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, 1, sharex=True, figsize=(15, 10))

# Plot the production decision
ax1.step(range(1, T+1), x_values, where='post', label="Production (x)", color='blue')
ax1.set_ylabel("Value")
ax1.legend()
ax1.grid(True)

# Plot the plant status
ax2.step(range(1, T+1), y_values, where='post', label="Plant running", color='red', linestyle='--')
ax2.step(range(1, T+1), batch_over_values, where='post', label="Plant started", color='blue', linestyle=':')
ax2.set_ylabel("Value")
ax2.legend()
ax2.grid(True)

# Setze die x-Achse für alle Achsen gleich
ax3.step(range(1, T+4), production_cost, where='post', label="Production Cost", color='green', linestyle=':')
ax3.set_ylabel("Value")
ax3.set_xlabel("Timesteps")
ax3.legend()
ax3.grid(True)
ax3.set_xlim(1, T+4)  # Setze die x-Achsen-Grenzen für alle Plots

# Füge Hilfslinien bei jedem Zeitschritt hinzu
ax3.set_xticks(range(1, T+5))  # Hier wird 5 anstelle von 4 verwendet, um auch den letzten Zeitschritt zu berücksichtigen

# Plot the summarizied production cost
ax3.step(range(1, T+4), production_cost_sum, where='post', label="Production Cost Sum", color='red', linestyle=':')
ax3.set_ylabel("Value")
ax3.set_xlabel("Timesteps")
ax3.legend()
ax3.grid(True)

for t in range(1, T+4):
    value = production_cost_sum[t-1]
    ax3.text(t, value, str(value), ha='center', va='bottom')

# Zeige die Grafik
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that "power" is synonymous with the production level, so if a run starts at time 5 with power of 3, it will produce 3 widgets in periods 5, 6, 7, and 8 for a total of 12 towards your production goal...

So here is an idea:  reformulate your problem.  It may have just gotten easier because the production is constant the run, right?  So as above, if I tell you it starts in period 5 with power 3, you know the outcome ==> you probably don't need the running/production variables.

So try reformulating your `start` variable as a binary to indicate the start occurred (to help with the constraint covering non-overlapping starts), and another `run_power` to be an integer, the power level for the start at any time period.  See if you can think of the constraints and the cost function in terms of just those 2 variables, which is still indexed by time.

Continuing the example above:

- If I tell you a run starts at t=5 at power 3, can you figure out the cost of that specific run by using the `run_power` variable?  (Yes.)  Something like:

---

```
 cost[5] = run_power[5] * sum(price[5-8])
```

- Can you aggregate that over all the periods that might have a `run_power` to get the total cost with a little creativity?  (Yes.)
- Can you re-use the constraint to prevent multiple overlapping runs and the binary `start` variable?  (Yes)
- Can you use a big-M constraint to link the `start` variable to the `run_power` variable at the same timestep?
- Can you (similar to cost) roll up the total # of widgets produced to make a constraint to make that greater than or equal to demand? ...

Comment: Thanks for your advice and for leading me to the right solution! My thoughts were much to complicated. I used your hints and I even solved it without a big M and I think its working. Thanks again! :)

Comment: My first solution required an adjustment of the optimized load profile. Means run_power representing the power for each batch. Now I added a storage after the process, this storage is constantly discharged (each timestep), why I can´t use my solution anymore. Unfortunatley I also don´t find a solution with your hints. If you can describe it in more detail I would be very thankfull :) I edited my starting post, tried to hold it simple as possible.

Comment: @Programmdrik. This problem seems to keep getting more complicated.  :/

Comment: The relationship between power, storage of ?, and production is totally unclear.  You need to probably spell that out very clearly in your question and it would help to do a small example by hand (a time table or something similar for a handful of steps) to illuminate what is going on with these variables.

Comment: I edited the post, I hope it's clear now. Furthermore, maybe I find already a solution, but I´m not sure if I miss anything because I don´t understand why it isn´t quadratic anymore.
I´m not sure what you mean by an example by hand. A desired load profile with values for both process steps?

Comment: I rolled back the question, to close this section and don´t mix different problems. The block production with the storage is solved. But I found another problem which I´m challenging here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77357816/how-to-model-a-contiuous-discharge-rate-for-a-storage-in-a-pyomo-optimization