# How to model a contiuous discharge rate for a storage in a pyomo optimization?

Tags: python, optimization, storage, pyomo

I am attempting to optimize a multi-stage industrial process. The objective function is the minimization of production costs. In the initial step, a liquid product is produced and added to a container. This container is connected to an open pipe, causing a constant outflow from the container when it is full. Since the maximum production of the liquid product exceeds the discharge rate of the container, the container serves as a limiting process step for the upstream process. I consider the container as an analogy to a storage. Currently, I am primarily facing challenges in modeling the storage and the constant discharge rate.

According to my understanding, I need to define a binary variable to indicate whether the storage can discharge or not.

I am currently implementing it as follows:

```
def energy_balance_rule(model, t):
    if t == 1:
        return model.energy[t] == model.charge[t] - model.discharge[t]
    else:
        return model.energy[t] == model.energy[t - 1] + model.charge[t] - model.discharge[t] * 3.75
model.energy_balance_con = pyo.Constraint(model.timesteps, rule=energy_balance_rule)

def discharging_rule1(model,t):
    if t > 1:
        return model.discharge[t] <= model.energy[t - 1]
    else:  
        return pyo.Constraint.Skip
model.discharging_con1 = pyo.Constraint(model.timesteps, rule=discharging_rule1)

def discharging_rule2(model,t):
    if t > 1:
        return model.discharge[t] * max_capacity >= model.energy[t - 1]
    else:  
        return pyo.Constraint.Skip
model.discharging_con2 = pyo.Constraint(model.timesteps, rule=discharging_rule2)
```

However, there seems to be an issue regarding the dependency of model.energy[t] on model.discharge[t], as model.discharge[t] depends on model.energy[t-1]. The optimization always ensures that production occurs at the end of the considered time period, even though it may not be the most cost-effective approach. See the graphic:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea of how I can address this issue?

Additional information: If the storage is completely emptied, the entire system must remain idle for 20 time steps. Therefore, theoretically, a discharge rate less than 3.75 could be possible when discharging to zero. However, I would like to initially disregard this possibility.

**Code**

```
    # 2. Define the decision variables.
# variables storage
model.charge = pyo.Var(model.timesteps, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals, initialize=0.0)  # charge
model.discharge = pyo.Var(model.timesteps, domain=pyo.Binary, initialize=0.0) # discharge
model.energy = pyo.Var(model.timesteps, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals, initialize=0.0)  # SOC
model.storage_status = pyo.Var(model.timesteps, domain=pyo.Binary, initialize=0.0)  # SOC > 0?
model.casting_off = pyo.Var(model.timesteps, domain=pyo.Binary, initialize=0.0)  # casting off (timestep with first SOC = 0)

# variables EAF
model.production = pyo.Var(model.timesteps, within=pyo.Integers)  # production decision
model.running = pyo.Var(model.timesteps, within=pyo.Binary)  # plant status
model.start = pyo.Var(model.timesteps, within=pyo.Binary)  # start of the plant
model.run_power = pyo.Var(model.timesteps, within=pyo.NonNegativeReals)  # power of the plant



# 3. Define the objective function.
def obj_rule(model):
    return sum(((production_cost[t-1] + production_cost[t] + production_cost[t+1] + production_cost[t+2]) * model.run_power[t]) for t in model.timesteps)
model.obj = pyo.Objective(rule=obj_rule, sense=pyo.minimize)



# 4. Define the constraints.

# Constraints EAF
# Total production constraint
def total_production_rule(model):
    return sum(model.run_power[t] for t in model.timesteps) == production_goal/4
model.total_production_con = pyo.Constraint(rule=total_production_rule)

# Production is only possible if plant is on
def production_on_rule_1(model, t):
    return model.run_power[t] <= model.start[t] * maxPower
model.production_on_con_1 = pyo.Constraint(model.timesteps, rule=production_on_rule_1)

def production_on_rule_2(model, t):
    return model.run_power[t] >= model.start[t] 
model.production_on_con_2 = pyo.Constraint(model.timesteps, rule=production_on_rule_2)

# Running if started in current or preceding 3 periods
def production_rule(model, t):
    return model.production[t] == sum(model.start[tt] for tt in range(t-3, t+1) if tt > 0) * sum(model.run_power[tt] for tt in range(t-3, t+1) if tt > 0)
model.running_con = pyo.Constraint(model.timesteps, rule=production_rule)

# Start if no start occurred in preceding 3 periods
def start_rule(model, t):
    return model.start[t] <= 1 - sum(model.start[tt] for tt in range(t-3, t) if tt > 0)
model.start_con = pyo.Constraint(model.timesteps, rule=start_rule)



# Constraints storage
def capacity_rule1(model, t):
    return model.energy[t] <= max_capacity
model.capacity_con1 = pyo.Constraint(model.timesteps, rule=capacity_rule1)

def capacity_rule2(model, t):
    return model.energy[t] >= 0
model.capacity_con2 = pyo.Constraint(model.timesteps, rule=capacity_rule2)

def energy_balance_rule(model, t):
    if t == 1:
        return model.energy[t] == model.charge[t] - model.discharge[t]
    else:
        return model.energy[t] == model.energy[t - 1] + model.charge[t] - model.discharge[t] * 3.75
model.energy_balance_con = pyo.Constraint(model.timesteps, rule=energy_balance_rule)

def charging_rule(model,t):
    return model.charge[t] == model.production[t]
model.charging_con = pyo.Constraint(model.timesteps, rule=charging_rule)

def discharging_rule1(model,t):
    if t > 1:
        return model.discharge[t] <= model.energy[t - 1]
    else:  
        return pyo.Constraint.Skip
model.discharging_con1 = pyo.Constraint(model.timesteps, rule=discharging_rule1)

def discharging_rule2(model,t):
    if t > 1:
        return model.discharge[t] * max_capacity >= model.energy[t - 1]
    else:  
        return pyo.Constraint.Skip
model.discharging_con2 = pyo.Constraint(model.timesteps, rule=discharging_rule2)



# 5. Solve the model
solver = pyo.SolverFactory('gurobi')
results = solver.solve(model)
```