# Finding best schedule using python and Linear programming Pulp - comparing values in LpVariable.dicts

Tags: python, schedule, pulp

I am trying to use PuLP with Python to optimise a schedule where the goal is to run a generator whenever the electricity prices are the highest.
One of my constraints is to limit the number of times the generator turns on or off. I am stuck with trying to write this out.
I define a dictionary with 12 values, each representing if the generator is on in that hour.

```
hours = range(12) # length of schedule
generator_on = LpVariable.dicts("Generator_On", hours, cat="Binary")  # Binary variable (1 if on, 0 if off)
```

And adding a constraint for the switch time like this, but it is not working for me.

```
# add 1 in list if previous hours state is not equal to his one and sum to get total number of state changes
prob += lpSum([1 if generator_on[i].value() != generator_on[i-1].value() else 0 for i in range(1, len(hours))]) <= max_state_changes, "Max_switch_time"
```

Is linear programming the right tool for this problem? Later I hope to add constraints that allow for a fuel tank to be considered as well, where fuel is constantly added to it and it must not be fully emptied or overfilled.

Full code:

```
from pulp import LpProblem, LpVariable, lpSum, LpMaximize
prob = LpProblem("GeneratorScheduling", LpMaximize) # maximize profit from generating electricity
# Decision variables
hours = range(12) # length of schedule
generator_on = LpVariable.dicts("Generator_On", hours, cat="Binary")  # Binary variable (1 if on, 0 if off)
electricity_prices = [10, 8, 12, 7, 15, 9, 11, 14, 10, 8, 13, 10]  # Example: hourly electricity prices
max_state_changes = 2  # Maximum allowed state changes
max_on_time = 6  # Maximum allowed consecutive on time
# Objective function: Maximize profit
prob += lpSum(electricity_prices[i] * generator_on[i] for i in hours), "Total_Profit"
# Constraints
prob += lpSum(generator_on[j] for j in range(12)) <= max_on_time, f"Max_On_Time"
prob += lpSum([1 if generator_on[i].value() != generator_on[i-1].value() else 0 for i in range(1, len(hours))]) <= max_state_changes, "Max_switch_time"
print(prob)
prob.solve()
print("Optimal Schedule:")
for i in hours:
    print(f"Hour {i + 1}: {'On' if generator_on[i].value() == 1 else 'Off'}")
print("Total Profit:", round(prob.objective.value(), 2))
```

Comment: See if this answer I posted last year helps you out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76883555/how-to-apply-a-constraint-so-that-a-generator-should-run-for-atleast-4-intervals/76885849#76885849

forget about the "min runtime" constraint in that, but the running/starting is what you want.  You can replicate in `pulp`.  You basically need 2 variables, 1 to indicate the start events that you wish to count, and second to keep track of "running" which can only be true if it starts in that period, or was running in last period.  It can shut off anytime, and will remain off till next start

Comment: Are the first start and the last stop counted as state changes? If so, this limits the solution to a single ON-segment.