# Time dependent optimization constraint Minimum and Maximum Runtime

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

I am attempting to model the hourly runtime of a plant. Contractually, if the decision is made to run the plant, it must be run for a minimum of `X = 3` hours and a maximum of `Y = 8` hours.

I am trying to model out the constraints so that if the decision is made to run in a day, it must run for X a minimum of X hours and a maximum of Y hours. From there, when the plant is no longer running the decision resets.

Here is my attempt at the constraints:

```
    optimizer = pyo.SolverFactory(solver, executable = solver_exe)
    # Define the model
    model = pyo.ConcreteModel(name = "HRCO") 
    
    # Generate a list of hourly datetime slots
    model.TIME_SLOTS = RangeSet(0, int((end_date - start_date).total_seconds() / 3600), name = "Hour Number")    

    model.Year = Param(model.TIME_SLOTS, initialize=pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start= start_date, end = end_date, freq='h'))[0].dt.year.to_dict())
    model.min_dispatch = Param(initialize = min_dispatch)
    model.max_dispatch = Param(initialize = max_dispatch)

    # Variables
    model.hours_to_run = Var(model.TIME_SLOTS, within=Binary)
    model.consecutive_hours = Var(model.TIME_SLOTS, within=NonNegativeIntegers, initialize = 0)

# Constraints
    for year in np.unique(pd.date_range(start= start_date, end = end_date, freq='h').year):
        year_slot = [slot for slot in model.TIME_SLOTS if model.Year[slot] == year]
        
        model.add_component("total_hours_constraint_{}".format(year),
                            Constraint(
            expr=sum(model.hours_to_run[slot] for slot in year_slot) <= max_hours
            ))
    
    def min_consecutive_hours_rule(model, t):
        if t == 0:
            return model.consecutive_hours[t] == model.hours_to_run[t]
        else:
            return model.consecutive_hours[t] == model.consecutive_hours[t-1] + model.hours_to_run[t]
        
    model.min_consecutive_hours_constraint = Constraint(model.TIME_SLOTS, rule=min_consecutive_hours_rule)

    def min_consecutive_hours_adjusted_rule(model, t):
        if t >= model.min_dispatch:
            return model.consecutive_hours[t] >= model.min_dispatch
        else:
            return Constraint.Skip

    model.min_consecutive_hours_constraint_adj = Constraint(model.TIME_SLOTS, rule=min_consecutive_hours_adjusted_rule)
    
    def max_consecutive_hours_rule(model, t):
        if t >= model.max_dispatch:
            return model.consecutive_hours[t] <= model.max_dispatch
        else:
            return Constraint.Skip

    model.max_consecutive_hours_constraint = Constraint(model.TIME_SLOTS, rule=max_consecutive_hours_rule)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply a constraint so that a generator should run for atleast 4 intervals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76883555/how-to-apply-a-constraint-so-that-a-generator-should-run-for-atleast-4-intervals)